The fifth son at the seder
I have heard multiple times about the fifth son at the Seder table, the one that isn't there.
Can anyone tell me the source or who said it?

It's based on the 4 sons representing various levels. Even the "wicked son" who is present has the ability to fix his ways. Unfortunately through assimilation there is another category of "sons" who didn't have a chance to be at seder and they should be encouraged to be able to join one

Read this article by Rabbi Sacks it’s my favorite Pesach dvar Torah: https://rabbisacks.org/archive/the-missing-fifth/

One of my favourite lectures. A must for all people who consider themselves frum https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xtjZ0JRCAQo&ab_channel=RabbiManisFriedman

I believe it was the Lubavitcher Rebbe, who, in a 1957 pre-Pessah letter, urged Jews worlwide to find and invite the "fifth son" to their seders.  This became the mission of Chabad.  You can read the text here:
https://www.chabad.org/therebbe/letters/default_cdo/aid/2064620/jewish/The-Fifth-Son-The-One-Not-Yet-at-the-Seder.htm

Correct - with the original Yiddish wording of the letter found here: https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=15912&st=&pgnum=49 "ליידער אבער איז פאראן ובפרט אין אונזער צייט פון חשך כפול ומכופל, נאק אן ארט בנים: דער קינד וואס איז גאר ניטא צום סדר" and a Hebrew translation of that letter found here: https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=15906&st=&pgnum=271

"...נאך אן ארט בנים..."

Rabbi Friedman goes through it in a 25 minute shiur https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xtjZ0JRCAQo&ab_channel=RabbiManisFriedman
